# Trying to run a python script as a service using systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, services

I just got a debian 8 VPS and I'm trying to run a python script as a service, I wrote this (everithing was done via ssh logged as root) :

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /web/cmcreader/test.py > /web/cmcreader/test.log 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've put it in `/lib/systemd/system`
I then chmoded it :

`chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/cmcreader.service`

I then tried to activate it using :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable cmcreader.service
```

however the last command returns (`enable`) :

`Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument`

What did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting at `man systemd.directives` you can find the docs for any systemd directive. Here you can find that `ExecStart=` is documented in `man systemd.service`.

The docs there say:

> redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.

They are also not usually needed. `systemd` already runs apps in the background by default, so you don't need `&`. It also automatically captures output to STDOUT and STDERR and logs it for you, so you don't need to redirect the output to a log file either.

Just use `journalctl -u cmcreader` to view the logs for your service, or `journalctl` to view all the logs.

If you aren't sure about the syntax  of a systemd file, you can use:

```
systemd-analyze verify ./path/to/your.service
```

Also, service files you create go in `/etc/systemd/system`. The `/lib` directory is for service file installed by packages, not humans.

Finally, `enable` doesn't start the service, it just runs the `[Install]` section, setting your app to start at boot.

To start the service use `systemctl start your.service`.

Comment: thanks it's working now, however I have no systemd-analyze, I'm guessing I have to get it using apt-get?

Comment: I believe this tool is usually shipped with systemd. I'm not sure where to get it if you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use shell redirection operators - systemd will not implicitly run the ExecStart line in a shell.

What it does do, is run the program you specify (`/usr/bin/python` in your example) with everything else being the argument to said program. You get an invalid argument error, because the `> /web/cmcreader/test.log 2>&1` part **is** an invalid argument to python.

While I certainly recommend that you simply use journalctl as anwsered by @mark-stosberg and remove everything from the redirection forward, if you *really* want your python script to write out to a file, you have a couple of options:

- rewrite your python to actually write to the logfile
- have systemd run a bash script that runs the python script and redirects the outputs
- have systemd run bash explicitly a la `ExecStart=bash -c "/usr/bin/python /web/cmcreader/test.py > /web/cmcreader/test.log 2>&1"`

Again, I do not really recommend these options - especially not the last one.